# How to get video natural resolution swift 3?

Tags: swift, swift3, avasset

I have problem that I can't solve, it is related to getting original/natural video size with AVFoundation. The only thing I receive back in width and height properties are strange CGFloat values. Here is the function caller and the function that is called.

```
let ZZZZZ = resolutionForLocalVideo(url: filePathClicked)

private func resolutionForLocalVideo(url: URL) -> CGSize? {
    guard let track = AVURLAsset(url: url).tracks(withMediaType: 
    AVMediaTypeVideo).first else { return nil }
    let size = track.naturalSize.applying(track.preferredTransform)
    return size
}
```

When I am breakpointing the ZZZZZ variable, it gives me back -

ZZZZZ   CGSize? (width = NaN, height = 6.9531301382845243E-310)

Sometimes it gives different values for width and height for even the same video.
The filePathClicked variable in breakpoint gives -

filePathClicked URL "file:///Users/ramix/Downloads/SampleVideo_1280x720_10mb%20copy%2010.mp4"

Nothing else is breaking, it is just these strange values I am receiving and I dont know what I can do with them. I wanted to get the resolution.

Thank you!

Comment: Interesting; never seen this behavior. What is the natural size without applying the `preferredTransform`? i.e., just `track.naturalSize`.

Comment: If I leave just track.naturalSize then its the same -
ZZZZZ CGSize? (width = NaN, height = 6.9531301382845243E-310)

Comment: Right. So the track.naturalSize is coming back as that. That means the video itself is coming back as that size. Thus, the app is reading the video as that size. Test with a different video and see if that is the case?

Comment: Just converted youtube to mp4 but it gives the same - ZZZZZ CGSize? (width = NaN, height = 6.9531301382845243E-310)

For file - filePathClicked URL "file:///Users/ramix/Downloads/Yelawolf%20-%20Best%20Friend%20ft.%20Eminem%20(Official%20Music%20Video).mp4"

Comment: Hrm. Yea. Try .mov format

Comment: Same thing, I dont understand, code is enough small to understand from where problem could come.